# Write (list 'test and) in Racket throws error

Tags: racket

Like the title says this list throws an error

`and: bad syntax in: and`

but how to write it then, need **and** in that list?

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `and` other than at the beginning of an s-expr because it is a reserved word, it seems.

So outside of that in other positions, you can use it only with `quote`, else it gives bad syntax error.

The only possibility to let it appear in the end of a list - thus - is:

```
`(test ,'and)
;; '(test and)
```

In addition, Racket makes a syntax-check (check whether a variable is bound or not) before evaluating. (And not when evaluating the expression like Common Lisp does).

```
(if '() whatever 3) ;; `whatever` being a variable not defined before.
;; common-lisp: 3
;; racket:  whatever: unbound identifier in module in: whatever
```

In Common Lisp, since it is a Lisp-2 (different namespaces between function and variable), you can even create/keep a variable with the name `and`:

```
;; CL: a variable with the name 'and'
(defvar and 3)
(list 1 and)
;; => (1 3)
```

However, also in Common Lisp, redefinition of a function `and` is not allowed:

```
;; CL: redefine function 'and' - doesn't work:
(defun and (&rest args) (apply #'or args))
;; *** - DEFUN/DEFMACRO: AND is a special operator and may not be redefined.
```

In Racket, it is impossible to bind sth to a reserved word like `and`.

So, since Racket is Lisp-1, any redefinition of `and` is not allowed (neither as variable name nor as a function name), and since Racket does syntax checking for bound variables before evaluating an s-expr - be it a special form/macro or a function - `and` in any other position than at the beginning of an s-expression cannot occur in Racket without a `quote`/`'`.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct lists, you need to quote each element.

```
Welcome to Racket v6.12.
> (list 'test 'and)
'(test and)
```

Comment: thanks but how to get **and** without ' ? I always get **'and**

Comment: @SmokeTM You mean that when you evaluate `'(test and)` you get something else than `(test and)`? Note that the REPL likes to display the symbol `and` and the list `(a b)` as `'and` and `'(a b)` but it really is `and` and `(a b)` since if you wrap it in `list` `(list '(a b))` you get `'((a b))` and not `'('(a b))`

Comment: if I write (car (cdr (list 'test 'and))) I get **'and** the same here (car (cdr '(test and))) but I need only **and** because I wanna use it with arguments

Comment: You need to use racket [quasiquoting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html) `(eval \`(,(last (list 'test 'and)) 1 2))`

Comment: I dont think so we haven't learned that until now, so I think we shouldn't use it. I can write that (list (cons '* (list 'test *))) but I cant write that (list (cons 'and (list 'test and))) and I dont now why. I tried hours know to solve this problem it now annoys me...

Comment: @noxdafox (eval `(,(last (list 'test 'and)) 1 2)) doesn't work in Racket- `and: unbound identifier` - neither in common lisp - `EVAL: (AND) is not a function name; try using a symbol instead`.